# Open Iframe in bootstrap modal on click

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to create a button that opens a modal containing an iframe. The iframe should only be loading once the modal opens. Right now when I click on my button to open the modal, nothing is loaded and no errors are given in console.

I am following an old snippet I found [here](https://www.bootply.com/61676) but it seems with a newer version of bootstrap, it does not seem to work.

Jquery

```js
var frameSrc = "http://test.com";

$('#ticketViewBtn').click(function(){
    $('#ticketView').on('show', function () {

        $('iframe').attr("src",frameSrc);
      
    });
    $('#ticketView').modal({show:true})
});
```

Bootstrap

```html
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="#ticketViewBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ticketView">
    TICKET
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="ticketView" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ticketViewLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="ticketViewLabel">TICKET</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe src="" height="600px" width="800px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for load the iframe .

```
$('#ticketViewBtn').click(function(){    
    var iframe_id = $("#myiframe");
    iframe.attr("src", iframe.data("src")); 
    $('#ticketView').modal({show:true})
});

<iframe id="myiframe" src="" height="600px" data-src="http://test.com" src="about:blank" width="800px" frameborder="0" onload="resizeIframe(this)" ></iframe>

function resizeIframe(iframe) {
    iframe.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok.. this is simple modal .. 
no jquery and no bootstrap
 just skeleton ..
Every link will **'target'** into **iframe_modal** in modal div

```css
.modal {
  z-index:3;
  display:none;
  padding-top:50px;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
  background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4)
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.example.com" onclick="document.getElementById('modal1').style.display='block'" target="iframe_modal" >example</a>  
<a href="https://www.bing.com"    onclick="document.getElementById('modal1').style.display='block'" target="iframe_modal">bing</a>

<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('modal1').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('iframe1').src =''" class="">&times;</span>
  <iframe id="iframe1" height="300px" width="100%" src="" name="iframe_modal"></iframe>
</div>
```

Using jquery:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com">example</a>
<a href="https://bing.com/"      >bing</a>

<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <span>&times;</span>
  <iframe id="iframe1" height="300px" width="100%" src="" ></iframe>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){  
        $("#modal1").show();
```

> when click an 'a', current (this) atribute href 'a' will be get and set
>   into src '#iframe1'

```
        $("#iframe1").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
        return false;
    });
    $("span").click(function(){
        $("#modal1").hide();
        $("#iframe1").attr("src", "");
    });    
});
```